# How to set the lambda parameter for xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

I have an interesting little issue:  there is a `lambda` regularization parameter to `xgboost`. Well.. they call it .. *lambda* .. which presents a problem when attempting to actually use that parameter:

```
models["xgboost"] = XGBRegressor(lambda=Lambda,n_estimators=NTrees 
   learning_rate=LearningRate, max_depth=MaxDepth, 
   max_features=MaxFeatures,rate_drop=0, loss="huber",eta=Eta, 
   gamma=Gamma,subsample=Subsample,colsample_bytree=Colsample_bytree,
                                  eval_metric=eval_metric)
```

Well.. `lambda` is as we know a *python keyword*.  So we have not made the compiler  .. *pleased* ..

```
    lambda=Lambda)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I looked into whether `python` supports escaping variable names. afaict it is *not* supported.  So .. how to set this parameter (short of using positional ..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XGBRegressor parameter you are looking for is `reg_lambda`, as you are using xgboost's [scikit-learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn).

You may then wonder why `xgb` has a parameter called `lambda`, which works without issue.  The reason is because the variable scope is local to the `train` method.